# How to unfold rows in a table

Tags: tables, ocgx

I am trying to unfold rows in a table, just like text can be created to be shown and hidden using ocgx package. The problem here is that if I enter that line (of creating corresponding row in table) in ocgx, it shows error (obviously, since the full tabular environment is not in the ocg environment, just the line with alignment characters).

I want an environment that can compile or not compile the code written in it at my wish (toggled by pressing a button). Is that possible?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
            Hi&Hello\\ \hline   
            \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{1}
                Hi&hello    \\ \hline
             \end{ocg}
    \end{tabular}
    
    \switchocg{ocg1}{Button.}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Another MWE based on answer of AlexG.

```
\usepackage{ocgx2} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document} 
    \noindent% 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
        This is &row 1\\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}\\[-\dimexpr\lineskip+\fboxrule\relax] 
    \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{on} 
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline 
            This is &row 2\\ \hline 
        \end{tabular}\\[-\dimexpr\lineskip+\fboxrule\relax]
    \end{ocg}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
        This is &row 3\\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}
    \noindent\switchocg{ocg1}{Button.} 
\end{document}
```

Note that on pressing the button, second row becomes invisible, but it is still there, that I don't want. It should be replaced by row 3 on pressing the button.

Comment: In your example, `\end{ocg}` is missing. Anyway, it will not work to span an environment across several tabular entries/lines, `ocg` or other.

Comment: @gernot, fixed the `\end{ocg}` problem. For your second line, note that `\verb` environment works to do its job irrespective of presence of anything in it. Something like that may also exist in this case, which compiles or comments a specific piece of code based on pressing a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment characters of `tabular` may not be used within *any* user-defined environment. (You may verify this with a no-op environment, such as `\newenvironment{bla}{}{}`).

One way to work around this could be wrapping every table row within a `tabular` of its own:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ocgx2} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
 
\newenvironment{blabla}{}{} 
 
\begin{document} 
    \noindent% 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
            Hi&Hello\\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}\\[-\dimexpr\lineskip+\fboxrule\relax] 
    \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{on} 
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline 
              Hi&Hello\\ \hline 
      \end{tabular} 
    \end{ocg} 
 
    \noindent\switchocg{ocg1}{Button.} 
\end{document}
```

"Unfolding" is not possible with the PDF format. In contrast to HTML, PDF is paginated content. After typesetting the stream of input, every glyph has its fixed position within a paragraph of text and within a page.

"Unfolding", as requested, would require re-typesetting the whole document during viewing time whenever text is hidden or shown by user-interaction, because the arrangement of paragraphs, the number of pages and even the table of contents would change. But, PDF viewers do not have a built-in (LaTeX-)typesetter.

Comment: It doesn't have the effect of unfolding rows, if used in the middle of a table, it just makes them invisible, when they aren't shown.

Comment: Please check out the edit in my post, the previous minimal working example turned out to be too minimal to make my motive clear.

Comment: I extended the answer a bit.

Comment: Ok thank you @AlexG, I would be happy if that were possible, though.