# How to remove whitespace in spoilers using the ocgx package

Tags: white-space, ocgx

I have been typing my notes in Microsoft word and I want to move to LaTeX because LaTeX has much greater control over formatting. My favorite word feature is being able to expand and collapse headings to hide or show large sections of the document. I got this test spoiler to work in Adobe Acrobat Reader:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcounter{secNum}
\newenvironment{spoiler}[1]
    {
        \stepcounter{secNum}
        \switchocg{\thesecNum}{#1}
        \begin{ocg}{\thesecNum}{\thesecNum}{0}
            
    }
    {
    \end{ocg}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{spoiler}{Example 1}
    Solve $4x+2=x-7$\\
    \begin{spoiler}{Solution}
        \begin{spoiler}{Move the constants to one side and $x$ terms to the other side}
            \[3x=-9\]
        \end{spoiler}
        \begin{spoiler}{Divide both sides by the coefficient of $x$}
            \[x=-3\]
        \end{spoiler}
    \end{spoiler}
\end{spoiler}

\begin{spoiler}{Example 2}
    Solve $4x+2=x-7$\\
    \begin{spoiler}{Solution}
        \begin{spoiler}{Move the constants to one side and $x$ terms to the other side}
            \[3x=-9\]
        \end{spoiler}
        \begin{spoiler}{Divide both sides by the coefficient of $x$}
            \[x=-3\]
        \end{spoiler}
    \end{spoiler}
\end{spoiler}

\end{document}
```

But there are two problems. The less important problem is that the "Move the constants to one side..." and "Divide both sides..." are indented but I don't want them to be indented. The main problem is that when the spoilers are closed there is a lot of white space which is the same size as the hidden text. I want the text following a spoiler to be moved upward when the spoiler is closed.

Is there a way to accomplish this with ocgx or another package? I would prefer not to have to use JavaScript but I am open to using JavaScript if that is the only way.

Comment: you are adding _lots_ of white space, use `%` at ends  of lines in your definitions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right adding a % between the two example spoilers reduced the vertical space so I will do that. I also tried adding % after the being{ocg} but then the headings were on the same line as the text being covered by the heading which I didn't want. However, I want with to remove all of the whitespace occupied by the text when the spoiler is closed. Adding the % reduced the whitespace but it can't get rid of the whitespace that replaces the text (e.g. 3x=9) when the spoiler is closed.

Comment: yes sure % (not between thes poilers but after `{` and after  `\setcounter` etc is just standard tex practice to avoid adding normal spaces. I don' know enough about ocg to answeryour main question I suspect it's not possible as it would require reflowing the entire rest of the document as you made text appear/disappear.

Comment: This is not possible. TeX produces paginated content with fixed positions of paragraphs, floats etc once the document has been typeset. Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590210

Comment: Also, PDF does not support this feature. It is only available in the Word editor and gets lost when the document is exported to PDF.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for letting me know. That is very unfortunate. There are a lot of strengths of LaTeX that Microsoft Word doesn't have but this feature is a dealbreaker for me. Is there something that has the same level of control over formatting as LaTeX (basically something code-based instead of typing-based) but has spoilers like Microsoft Word? I am considering doing a website instead but is it possible to do everything you can do with LaTeX in a webpage?

Comment: It seems that MathJax is the replacement for LaTeX for websites (and I know websites support spoilers). This website has an exhaustive list of what MathJax can do: https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm. I am hoping that everything I want to do in LaTeX is also possible with MathJax.